# Regular expression with letters, numbers and dashes, but with no leading or trailing dash

Tags: regex

In my ASP.NET MVC project is a regular expression for validating a string with alphanumeric characters and dashes, while also not allowing leading or trailing dashes:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}?)(\-{0,}?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}?))+$
```

This works for most use cases:

```
safename                (valid)
123                     (valid)
there-is-something-here (valid)
your-name-goes-here     (valid)
-something-is-up        (invalid)
say-what-               (invalid)
```

However, there are some use cases that I want to be valid, but are not:

```
a-b                     (valid)
a-bc-d                  (valid)
ab-cd-e                 (valid)
a-bc-de                 (valid)
this-is-a-test          (invalid)
a-b-c                   (invalid)
1-2-3                   (invalid)
```

I can have a single leading and/or trailing character, but not a single character within the rest of the string. I want `a-b-c` or `1-2-3` to be valid, but any modifications I've tried haven't yielded the desired results. I made a minor change to the first and third groups, but leading and trailing dashes pass:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}?)(\-{0,}?)([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}?))+$
```

I've reached my limit on regular expressions and would appreciate any guidance. Is the result I'm looking for possible with a single expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:--?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

If you want to allow only a single dash between each alphanumeric chars. Otherwise, turn the `-` to `-+` for multiple dashes.

Comment: This works, but only if I change `{2,}` to `{1,}`. Does that sound right? Kudos to having it limit multiple dashes since that's something I would like to have had but wasn't a priority.

Comment: @Mathachew Ohh, I misread your examples xD Yes, if you want to make `a-b-c` valid, then yes, you use `{1,}` or simply `+`. :)

Comment: I overlooked one other use case for single words. I've updated my examples and modified your expression to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[(^-|-)]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$`. The only issue I'm hitting at this point is if I use numbers only. Also, double dashes are allowed.

Comment: @Mathachew Double dashes meaning 2 or more or up to 2 dashes? I edited my answer for up to two dashes and the number only.

Comment: It can be two or more, so I replaced the second - with + and now I have what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Mathachew Awesome then! You should have `-+` instead of `--+` then, otherwise, you won't get the singlet hyphens allowed ^^

Answer (score 2):

I tried all your use cases with that expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$
```

1-2-3 is valid; 1-2- is not valid

Comment: I overlooked one other use case for single words. I've updated my examples and modified your expression to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([(^-|-)]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$`. Like the accepted answer, the only issue I'm hitting at this point is if I use numbers only. Double dashes are allowed.

Comment: If you would like double dashes only in case of numbers you should use this expression:

^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([-]{1,2}+[0-9]+))+$

Your expression allows double dashes before non numeric values.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that two or more dashes were allowed. The issue was `123` or `name` were invalid when I need them to be valid. The accepted answer works with those requirements. Thanks for the answer, it's always interesting to see how to accomplish the same result with different expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do, also prevents multiple dashes:

```
^(\w|(?<=\w)-(?=\w))+$
```

Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/sG6cL1).

Comment: This is great, but the only issue is that we don't allow underscores. I know to replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, but the accepted answer accomplished the same result with less.

Comment: Ah, yes, the underscore. That makes Jerry's shorter indeed :)